# Samsung Galaxy S4 "Prevention Information" USB OTG

Tags: usb, usb-peripherals

I am trying to connect things to my S4 with a USB OTG cable. Standard devices such as mass storage, keyboard and mouse all work fine. My problem seems to be with vendor class devices.

I connected an FTDI USB to UART bridge (TTL-232R-3V3) to a USB OTG cable and installed the FTDI app. I plugged in the OTG cable and the phone reccognised the FTDI chip, launched the app, waited a few seconds and then closed the app again.

I got the message:

"Prevention Information, An application has been forced to stop for an unauthorized attempt to access system in your device". (Including the grammatical error)

I have the same problem with my Arduino Uno using the ArduinoDriod app.

I tried both devices on a friend's Huawei p6 and they both worked fine. From what I can tell, this issue is specific to the S4 and seems to be related to the recent update to Samsung Knox.

Does anyone know of a work around that doesn't involve rooting the device?

I am still in the 14 day trial period of the phone, so I could swap it for a different one. How do I tell if the Galaxy Note 3 or the LG G2 will have the same problem?

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site anymore for more than 5 years, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

I did also read about this. KNOX seems to be blocking the communication to USB devices in some cases.

The Google Nexus 5 (LG) is also available now. Its pretty cheap for the features it offers. You should take a look at it before you swap you device. There is also a ROOT available for the SGS4 but it would break your warranty ofcourse:

[This is where i read it](http://www.extreamsd.com/USBAudioRecorderPRO/)

[more about the root. only use the one from the xda-developers forum!](https://plus.google.com/+Chainfire/posts/WqS2E9kkN1L/)

Comment: Thanks for the source re- knox causing problems with OTG.

I think I'm going to take the plunge and buy a Xperia Z1.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, and I did a backup on my PC using KIES and factory restored the phone. Then I reconnected the device to my PC, it found the backup made with KIES and then I restored my information from my KIES back-up on the pc back to the phone.

Comment: Did you mean doing a factory reset will fix the USB OTG issue? As of current writing, it isn't really clear if that's the case...